# Setting selected item in combobox bound to dictionary

Tags: .net, winforms, dictionary, combobox, selecteditem

I have a combobox that is bound to a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> comboboxValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
comboboxValues.Add(30000, "30 seconds");
comboboxValues.Add(45000, "45 seconds");
comboboxValues.Add(60000, "1 minute");
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboboxValues , null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

I'm getting the key from the SelectedItem like this:

```
int selection = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Key;
```

So if my user chooses the "45 seconds" option, I get back 45000 and save that value to an XML file.  When my application is loaded, I need to read that value and then automatically set the combobox to match.  Is it possible to do this when I only the key of 45000?  Or do I need to save the value ("45 seconds") to the file instead of the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you could use just the 45000

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboboxValues[45000];
```

If you know the index then you can use

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

i is zero based and -1 means no selection.

Or set the SelectedItem

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(45000, "45 seconds");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> comboboxValues = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    comboboxValues.Add(30000, "30 seconds");
    comboboxValues.Add(45000, "45 seconds");
    comboboxValues.Add(60000, "1 minute");
    comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboboxValues, null);
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboboxValues[45000];
}
```

Comment: I had been trying your first suggestion (comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboboxValues[45000];) but it wasn't working for me.  No error occured, it just didn't produce the desired effect.  I'm currently using a switch statement for the key and then setting the SelectedItem per your third suggestion.  This works for me but I feel like hardcoding the switch values isn't a very flexible solution.  Any thoughts on why your first suggestion doesn't seem to work?

Comment: That was from code I actually tested.   I hope you put that kvp in the Dictionary first?  And bound it.

Comment: Very odd.  I just created a new WinForms app, pasted your exact code above into the Form1_Load event handler and stepped through it in the debugger.  When my form appears, the combobox shows "30 seconds" (as I was expecting with the comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboboxValues[30000]; statement).  However, I then went back and edited that line to be comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboboxValues[45000] and when the form appears, the combobox still shows "30 seconds" instead of "45 seconds".  I must be missing something obvious here if it works for you but I sure don't know what it is.  :-(

Comment: You did compile after you changed the value?

Comment: Sure did.  Very, very strange.  I'll have to spend some time trying to figure out what's going on.  This should be ridiculously simple and works for you yet doesn't do the trick for me.  ARGH!  Thank you nevertheless for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue=45000
```

and your combo box will be pre selected by using Key