# Dynamically added Dropdownlist's SelectedValue not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating combobox dynamically in winforms

```
        ComboBox ddCntrl = new ComboBox();
        ddCntrl.Width = 100;
        ddCntrl.Name="dd_" + tpObj.RowColId;
        ddCntrl.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        Dictionary<int, string> DC = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        DC[-1] = "N/A";
        DC[0] = "Y";
        DC[1] = "N";

        ddCntrl.DataSource = new BindingSource(DC,null);
        ddCntrl.DisplayMember = "Value";
        ddCntrl.ValueMember = "Key";

         ddCntrl.SelectedIndex = ddCntrl.Items.IndexOf("N");
         TableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(ddCntrl, 1, 1);
```

I tried couple of option to set the selected value  nothing is working

I tried below options to set selected value
               ddCntrl.SelectedValue ="N";
              ddCntrl.SelectedIndex = ddCntrl.FindStringExact("N")

Comment: What does ddCntrl.Items.IndexOf("N"); returns? I guess it is not returning a correct value. Please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608189/setting-selected-item-in-combobox-bound-to-dictionary

Comment: it is returning index value -1

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608189/setting-selected-item-in-combobox-bound-to-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change some things. First, if you are using this code in the constructor, you will need to move it to `Load` or `Shown` event.

And set the index after add the comboBox to the panel. `ddCntrl.FindStringExact("N")` should works ok:

```
ComboBox ddCntrl = new ComboBox();
ddCntrl.Width = 100;
ddCntrl.Name = "dd_";
ddCntrl.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

Dictionary<int, string> DC = new Dictionary<int, string>();
DC[-1] = "N/A";
DC[0] = "Y";
DC[1] = "N";

ddCntrl.DataSource = new BindingSource(DC, null);
ddCntrl.DisplayMember = "Value";
ddCntrl.ValueMember = "Key";

tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(ddCntrl, 1, 1);
ddCntrl.SelectedIndex = ddCntrl.FindStringExact("N");
```

Comment: Thanks you, after adding combobox to panel ddCntrl.SelectedIndex = ddCntrl.FindStringExact("N") is working

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding to a Dictionary you should set selected item as follows:`ddCntrl.SelectedItem = DC[1];`

If you would like to set depending on display value (which i really do not suggest) you have to find it in DC and then set it to ddlCntrl

Comment: It is not working, do we have to do differently from dynamically created controls?

Comment: oh i see :) Please set the selectedvalue/item or index whatever you want after you add it to tablelayout :))